# wxBitmapButton reading class parameters

Tags: c++, class, parameters, wxwidgets

I have been trying to solve this problem for several hours now, but neither my wxWidgets knowledge (I'm a beginner) nor looking for an answer on-line didn't help me with this.

I've created a class called *Field* with three parameters *int x*, *int y* and *wxBitmapButton button*. Now, what I want to do is that when the *button* is clicked the event handler connected to that *button* would read the *x* and *y* from the **same** class instance that contains the used *button*.

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to read given coordinates Field::x, Field::y by clicking on Field::button. Could someone help me with this task?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume `Field` is not a widget itself (in case it is, things are similar, you'll just have to change the way it's created). One way of writing it is:

```
struct Field
{
   Field(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) { }

   void set_button(wxBitmapButton* btn)
   {
      button = btn;
      button->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [this](wxCommandEvent&)
      {
         //Do whatever you want with x and y 
         //(they're accessed through the captured this pointer).
         //For example:
         wxMessageBox(std::to_wstring(x) + ", " + std::to_wstring(y));
      });
   }

   int x;
   int y;
   wxBitmapButton* button = nullptr;
};
```

To test it, you could create a simple window like this:

```
struct test_frame : wxFrame
{
   test_frame() : wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, L"Test"), fld(3, 7) { }

   //fld doesn't have to be a member of the wxFrame-derived class; 
   //it just needs to live at least as long as the button it references.
   //This is just an example that satisfies that condition.
   Field fld;
};
```

And initialize everything like this:

```
auto main_frame = new test_frame();
auto btn = new wxBitmapButton(main_frame, wxID_ANY, your_bitmap);
main_frame->fld.set_button(btn);
main_frame->Show();
```

You'll have a message box displaying `3, 7` (or whatever values are in `x` and `y`, of course) pop up when the button is clicked.

---

All this code assumes you have a reasonably up-to-date compiler - it uses quite a few C++11 features, as you can see. It can all be done in many other ways, of course, but modern C++ makes things so nice and easy, I just can't resist...